# How to get particular column name and assigned an array using PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I have the following columns in `users` table

```
id username  rights_reports  rights_notify  rights_users  rights_supporting  lang  deleted

1   admin     1                 1               1           1                 en    0
2   subadmin  1                 0               0           1                 en    0
```

I want to check the access permission for users.

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id`='1'";
$resul = tdbQuery($sql);
$data = $result->fetch_assoc();
$permission = array('rights_reports'=>$data['rights_reports'],'rights_notify'=>$data['rights_notify'],'rights_users'=>$data['rights_users'],'rights_supporting'=>$data['rights_supporting']);
$_SESSION['access']=$permission;
?>
```

Here, can I get the particular column from the table like,  COLUMN NAME  LIKE `rights_`  and this value automatically assigned array?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT rights_reports,rights_notify,rights_users,rights_supporting 
        FROM `users` WHERE `id`='1'";
$_SESSION['access'] = tdbQuery($sql)->fetch_assoc();
```

better yet, you have to store rights in the rows, not columns. And use PDO instead of mysqli. So, the proper code would be

```
$sql = "SELECT r.name, ur.value FROM user_rights ur, rights r 
        WHERE user_id=? AND r.id = ur.rights_id";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([1]);
$_SESSION['access'] = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);
```

tables are: `rights`

```
id | name
1  | reports
2  | notify
3  | users
4  | supporting
```

and `user_rights`

```
user_id | rights_id
      1 |         1
      1 |         4
```

This is how databases *intended* to work